# Растягиваемый html модуль со встроенной графикой с изменяемой шириной

Tags: html

Нужно реализовать вот такую вещь:
Растягиваемый html модуль со встроенной графикой с изменяемой шириной от 728 до 1024 пикс и общей высотой модуля 90 пикс.
Вот я и думаю как это сделать чтобы картинка могла размеры менять... кто подскажет?

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет: [Динамический ресайз картинок](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/53912/)